# Comparing all possible pairs of consecutive variables

Tags: spss

I'm analyzing data for a study that is assessing the responses of patients to blood transfusions in terms of blood count. For every transfusion, there is an indicator variable that reflects whether the patient's blood counts improved sufficiently or not, depending on a pre-specified cut-off. A value of 1 indicates **insufficient** response, and 0 indicates **acceptable** response.

Every patient has at least 2 and up to 31 transfusions recorded as 31 variables: T1, T2, ..., T31. The data looks something like this:

```
Patient     T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  …   T31     
1           1   1   0   M   M   M   …   M       "Refractory"
2           0   0   0   0   M   M   …   M       "Not refractory"
3           0   0   1   1   0   M   …   M       "Refractory"
4           1   0   0   0   1   1   …   1       "Refractory"
```

The analysis requires computing an overall "refractoriness" status that reflects the aggregate response to blood transfusions. A patient is considered "refractory" if they had at least 2 **consecutive** transfusions with insufficient response. Otherwise, they are considered "non-refractory".

The simplest, most straightforward way (but not necessarily the nicest-looking) I thought of was to use combinations of logical statements to test for all the possible combinations of having two consecutive values of 1, like this:

```
COMPUTE Refractory=
Transfusion.1 and Transfusion.2 or
Transfusion.2 and Transfusion.3 or
Transfusion.3 and Transfusion.4 or
Transfusion.4 and Transfusion.5 or
Transfusion.5 and Transfusion.6 or
Transfusion.6 and Transfusion.7 or
Transfusion.7 and Transfusion.8 or
Transfusion.8 and Transfusion.9 or
Transfusion.9 and Transfusion.10 or
Transfusion.10 and Transfusion.11 or
Transfusion.11 and Transfusion.12 or
Transfusion.12 and Transfusion.13 or
Transfusion.13 and Transfusion.14 or
Transfusion.14 and Transfusion.15 or
Transfusion.15 and Transfusion.16 or
Transfusion.16 and Transfusion.17 or
Transfusion.17 and Transfusion.18 or
Transfusion.18 and Transfusion.19 or
Transfusion.19 and Transfusion.20 or
Transfusion.20 and Transfusion.21 or
Transfusion.21 and Transfusion.22 or
Transfusion.22 and Transfusion.23 or
Transfusion.23 and Transfusion.24 or
Transfusion.24 and Transfusion.25 or
Transfusion.25 and Transfusion.26 or
Transfusion.26 and Transfusion.27 or
Transfusion.27 and Transfusion.28 or
Transfusion.28 and Transfusion.29 or
Transfusion.29 and Transfusion.30 or
Transfusion.30 and Transfusion.31.
```

However, the computation returned much more missing values than expected. I don't really know why this is the case but I suspect this has to do with the way `and` and `or` operators handle missing values, as well as the fact that, for most rows in the data, there will be a lot of missing values by nature of the way the data are recorded. The following missingness map (produced using R) illustrates this (red = missing):
[image]

What would be a better way to compute the "refractoriness" status while properly handling missing values?

Answer (score 0):

With your command built like that, one missing value in any of the `Transfusion` variable will result in `Refractory` being also missing.

Here are two ways you can get your result without this problem:

**looping:**

```
do repeat v1=Transfusion.1 to Transfusion.30   
         /v2=Transfusion.2 to Transfusion.31 .   
   if v1=1 and v2=1 Refractory=1.   
end repeat.
```

**restructure:**

```
varstocases /make Transfusion from Transfusion.1 to Transfusion.31 .
if $casenum>1 and patient=lag(patient) and Transfusion=1 
    and lag(Transfusion)=1 Refractory=1.
dataset declare results. 
aggregate /out=results /BREAK=patient /Refractory=max(Refractory).
```